# Glacier Express Website Booking Issues

Tags: trains, bookings

I want to take the Glacier Express from Zermatt and disembark at St. Moritz. We are a couple, and both of us hold the Swiss Travel Flexi pass, so we only need to reserve our seats by paying the seat reservation fee. On http://www.glacierexpress.ch, when I go to the Bookings, it shows me that 6 seats are available for my day of travel. When I select a connection, the page just hangs, with the message 'Checking availability'.

[image]

Has anyone experienced this issue and is there an alternative to reserve seats?

Comment: If you are in Switzerland, I think you can also reserve the seats at SBB offices in bigger stations.

Comment: I am flying to Geneva tomorrow. Maybe, I will check with the SBB office at Geneva central station.

Comment: There's an SBB office at the railway station right next to Geneva airport. Follow the signs at exit which will lead you to "Geneva Airport" railway station and then you should be able to find the staffed SBB office there. See the [website](https://www.sbb.ch/content/internet/sbb/en/bahnhof-services/am-bahnhof/bahnhoefe/bahnhof-geneve-aeroport/geschaefte/shop-detail.html/geo-beratungstermin-f6d9)

Comment: I just tried it on the Glacier Express website and even though it sometimes takes a few seconds to show availabilities, it always ends up showing them. Maybe you tried at a time when the server was a bit too busy or something. You may want to retry now.

Comment: Note that the 8:52 train on 28/8 only has 1 seat left in 1st class. The 9:52 train has more availabilities. And the site is indeed sometimes quite slow (but in my case it always ends up giving a result)